# GraphQL does not allow to insert array objects in NodeJS

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose, graphql

Unfortunately getting error when insert array objects. Here the  code

**GraphQL Schema**

```
type Member {
  _id: ID!
  member_id: Int!
  first_name: String!
  last_name: String
  username: String
  date: String
}

input MemberInput {
  member_id: Int!
  first_name: String!
  last_name: String
  username: String
  date: String
}

type RootQuery {
  groups: [Group!]!
  members: [Member!]!
  member(member_id: Int!): Member!
}
type RootMutation {
  createGroup(groupInput: GroupInput): Group
  createMember(memberInput: [MemberInput]): Member
}
schema {
  query: RootQuery
  mutation: RootMutation
}
```

**Making array objects**

```
const mutatedAdminsDetails = groupAdminsFull.map(groupAdmin => {
  const rObj = {
    member_id: groupAdmin.id,
    first_name: groupAdmin.first_name,
    last_name: groupAdmin.last_name || '',
    username: groupAdmin.username || '',
    date: new Date().toISOString(),
  };
  return rObj;
});
```

Array objects **mutatedAdminsDetails**

```
[
  {
    member_id: 152356245,
    first_name: 'Subhash',
    last_name: 'Akbar',
    username: 'subhashbhai',
    date: '2019-07-26T14:39:01.314Z'
  },
  {
    member_id: 12312322,
    first_name: 'Shreef',
    last_name: '',
    username: '',
    date: '2019-07-26T14:39:01.314Z'
  }
]
```

**GraphQL mutation query**

```
const requestAdminBody = {
  query: `
      mutation {
        createMember(memberInput:
          [${mutatedAdminsDetails}]
        ) {
          _id
          member_id
          first_name:
        }
      }
    `
};
```

**API request**

```
const insertAdmins = await fetch('http://localhost:3000/graphql', {
  method: 'POST',
  body: JSON.stringify(requestAdminBody),
  headers: {
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
  }
})
  .then(res => {
    return res.json();
  })
  .then(resData =>
    resData
  )
  .catch(err => err )
```

Error in terminal

[image]

Comment: For the second error `group_id` doesn't exist in the Member's schema definition

Comment: @VladMamaev Changed, now getting this error ```{
  errors: [
    {
      message: 'Syntax Error: Expected Name, found [',
      locations: [Array]
    }
  ]
}```

Comment: @Fraction fixed the typo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to update your mutation to:

```
const requestAdminBody = {
  query: `
      mutation CreateMember($memberInput: [MemberInput]){
        createMember(memberInput: $memberInput) {
          _id
          first_name
        }
      }
    `,
  variables: { memberInput: mutatedAdminsDetails }
};
```

Comment: Getting this error ```{ errors: [ { message: 'Must provide query string.' } ] }```

Comment: unfortunately getting this error now ```errors: [
    {
      message: 'Unknown type "memberInput". Did you mean "MemberInput" or "Member"?',
      locations: [Array]
    },
    {
      message: 'Cannot query field "name" on type ' +
        '"Member". Did you mean "date" or ' +
        '"username"?',
      locations: [Array]
    }
  ]```

Comment: the message tells you the answer, I've updated my answer ^^

Comment: Getting this error```{
  errors: [
    {
      message: 'Cannot return null for non-nullable field Member._id.',
      locations: [Array],
      path: [Array]
    }
  ],
  data: { createMember: null }
}``` any idea about it ?

Comment: I think you don't return the created member from your db, you can try something like: `const doc = await Member.create(member); return Member.findById(doc._id)`

Comment: @Franction is it ok for that ```const results = await Member.insertMany(newAdmins);
return results.map(result => {
  return { ...result._doc };
});```

Comment: The insert function works but some how response coming like this `{ errors:
   [ { message: 'Cannot return null for non-nullable field Member._id.',
       locations: [Array],
       path: [Array] } ],
  data: { createMember: null } }`

Comment: You can *console.log* `results` to see what it returns

Comment: The response is ```errors:
   [ { message:
        'Cannot return null for non-nullable field Member.first_name.',
       locations: [Array],
       path: [Array] } ],
  data: { createMember: null } }```